# Einstein Prediction Builder for Loyalty Management objects

Tags: einstein, loyalty-management

I have a client where we are exploring possibilities of Einstein Prediction Builder. They are using Loyalty Management and we would like use those standard Salesforce loyalty objects for predictions.

We went into Einstein Prediction Builder, but the Transaction Journal object (for example) is not available to select under the list of available objects to build predictions on. I've read the list of available standard object for predictions, and there is now word about Loyalty Management there and I am not able to find anything regrading this.

Is it possible to use Loyalty Management objects in Einstein Prediction Builder?

If not, would Einstein Discovery be something to look at?

I found something about [Loyalty Analytics Plus](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.analytics_limitations.htm&type=5) license under CMR Analytics, but this seems to be yet another platform and license which clients currently doesn't have.

We would basically like to leverage the existing Einstein Prediction Builder license with Loyalty management and build prediction based on the data. If possible, without creating some custom object that would be storing the data only for this purpose.

Any feedback or insight would be helpful.
Thank you